# Merge two tables on sql when keys don't fully match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So basically I want to perform a very simple action and I can't think of a simple work around to merge two tables and sum the number of days.

Imagine my tables are these.

T1

```
id   |   days
---  -  ------
 1   |     2
 2   |     4
 3   |     1
```

T2

```
id   |   days
---  -  ------
 1   |     2
 3   |     1
 4   |     2
```

So my output should look like this

```
id   |   days
---  -  ------
 1   |     4
 2   |     4
 3   |     2
 4   |     2
```

I've tried using full outer join, but then I can't select the id column because it's ambiguous. Another thing I've thought is to do a UNION and group by id and sum days, but this would be very hard (since my data is way more complicated than this example and have several columns).

I'm working on Big Query.

Comment: if you reference the column `ID` like `T1.ID` and `T2.ID` the ambiguity should vanish

Comment: can you put the query in that you attempted?  Thanks

Comment: I think your table is not normalized properly that's why you get this type of problem tries to normalized at least up to `2nf`.

Comment: Using T1 or T2 won't help, since I want the union of both and if I write T1.ID I would have 1, 2, 3, null and with T2 1, null, 3, 4.

So I've tried this: `select * from t1 full join t2 on t1.id=t2.id`

I don't get what you mean by normalizing my table, I just want to merge two tables, it's not that I have an error rather than I don't know how to do it.

Comment: how you calculated days as `2` for id = 2 ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I made a mistakes, basically I want days to be the sum of both columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full outer join -

```
   select
     coalesce(table1.id,table2.id) as id,
     coalesce(table1.days,0)+coalesce(table2.days,0)
   from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: @sergiomahi, I've updated the answer with full outer join - you can check  if it works in your case

Comment: @sergiomahi . . . As the other answer points out, you could use `using` to avoid the `coalesce()` on the `id`.  I think that would have been better served as a comment than a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> I've tried using full outer join, but then I can't select the id column because it's ambiguous

You can use `USING()` instead of `ON` to eliminate such an ambiguity

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, IFNULL(t1.days, 0) + IfNULL(t2.days, 0) AS says
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING(id)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 days UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 days UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 
)
SELECT id, IFNULL(t1.days, 0) + IFNULL(t2.days, 0) AS says
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING(id)
```

with output

```
Row id  days     
1   1   4    
2   2   4    
3   3   2    
4   4   2
```

Comment: I like the answer. why to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` in this case, as `FULL JOIN` works . Just a question !

Comment: autocomplete feature! - type FULL and then CTRL+SPACE